# jQuery bubble like the one on stackoverflow?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I like the orange bubbles that appears on SO as a warning: Is there a jQuery plugin for that?

Answer (score 0):

What about this one: http://www.lullabot.com/files/bt/bt-latest/DEMO/index.html